# not defined variable K-means clustering

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

It seems that there is a variable not defined in this code.

```py
cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=217)
matrix['cluster'] = cluster.fit_predict(matrix[x_calls])
cluster
```

As a result, I got an error like the below information when I tried to run the file.

```py
NameError: name 'x_calls' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't get your problem, clearly it says `x_calls` is not defined, hence the error you get. Maybe you meant `matrix['x_calls']`

Comment: i dont get the problem too, no its **matrix[x_calls]**